# Hot to use coqui-ai TTS to turn a text file to audio?

Tags: go, text-to-speech

I want to use [coqui-ai TTS](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS) but it has problems dealing with short sentences so I've made a go script to only keep the sentences that don't give an error when converting and then merging all the audios.

The script works fine for the most part but on the small sentences it makes weird sounds and usually produces longer audios than it should.

I think the best thing to do is figure out what is the average audio length per character and if a sentence's audio length is above the expected length by a certain margin truncate the excess. How could I do this in go?

This is the code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/cheggaaa/pb/v3"
    "github.com/neurosnap/sentences/english"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        log.Fatalf("Usage: go run main.go <input>")
    }
    sentences := get_sentences()
    audio_files := convert_text_to_audio(sentences)
    concatenate_audio_files(audio_files)
}

func get_sentences() []string {
    tokenizer, err := english.NewSentenceTokenizer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    text, err := os.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tmp := tokenizer.Tokenize(string(text))
    var sentences []string
    for _, sentence := range tmp {
        sentences = append(sentences, sentence.Text)
    }
    return sentences
}

func convert_text_to_audio(sentences []string) []string {
    var audio_files []string
    bar := pb.StartNew(len(sentences))
    for i, sentence := range sentences {
        audio_file := "out_" + strconv.Itoa(i) + ".wav"
        cmd := exec.Command("tts", "--text", sentence, "--model_name", "tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DDC", "--out_path", audio_file)
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(cmd.String())
            log.Println("Failed to run coqui-ai tts")
        } else {
            audio_files = append(audio_files, audio_file)
        }
        bar.Increment()
    }
    bar.Finish()
    return audio_files
}

func concatenate_audio_files(audio_files []string) {
    audio_files = append(audio_files, "out.wav")
    cmd := exec.Command("sox", audio_files...)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to run sox")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code that save wav and run it

```
 model_name = "tts_models/en/vctk/vits"

    # Init TTS
    tts = TTS(model_name)

def play_wav():
    # Open the input WAV file
    with wave.open("output.wav", "rb") as f:
        # Get the sample rate and number of channels
        sample_rate = f.getframerate()
        num_channels = f.getnchannels()
        # Read the entire waveform into memory
        frames = f.readframes(f.getnframes())

    # Convert the waveform to an AudioSegment object
    audio = AudioSegment(
        data=frames,
        sample_width=f.getsampwidth(),
        frame_rate=sample_rate,
        channels=num_channels
    )

    # Increase the speed by a factor of X
    new_audio = audio.speedup(playback_speed=1.05)

    # Play the modified audio
    play(new_audio)


    tts.tts_to_file(text="Hi this a test", speaker="p243", file_path="output.wav")
    play_wav()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34165994)